# capture URL in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Try to capture the url chrome browser using  chrome extension background script.

I try below code is working fine for new url change but not working in tab change

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
           chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(tab.url);
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Test Extension",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
      "tabs",
       "activeTab",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

console log print once when it install after that no response.

I want to capture URL of current tab... when user change the browser tab or create new tab I need to capture the url of the current browser tab in background without click extension icons.

After get the URL I need to append one query string at the end of the URL.

for example

current tab url : stackoverflow.com
extension change/append url : stackoverflow.com/question/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code working fine as expected

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function( tabId,  changeInfo,  tab) {
       chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(tab.url);
       if(tab.url=="https://www.google.co.in/"){
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: 'https://www.yahoo.com/'});
       }
});
```

let me know the comments

Comment: Just thought I would point out that since you already have the code in your background page you can just use `console.log` directly instead of through `getBackgroundPage`

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the onUpdated event.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(integer tabId, object changeInfo, Tab tab) {...});
```

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated

Answer (score 0):

1) Event for when the active tab is changed:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(object activeInfo) {...});
```

[From documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated):

> Fires when the active tab in a window changes. Note that the tab's URL may not be set at the time this event fired, but you can listen to onUpdated events to be notified when a URL is set.

2) Most likely, you also need to listen to the [chrome.windows.onFocusChanged](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onFocusChanged) event which is fired when the currently focused window is changed.

Comment: thanks tanushree but onActivated information given tab id and windowid Object {tabId: 697, windowId: 673} but onUpdated.addListener works but I dont why it return url 3times or 2 times I think due to some callback